# All parent table rows left jon child table directly

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, left-join, where-clause

I have three tables: patron, patron_address, and patron_phone
for every patron/

Patron has 1-3 Patron_address rows
patron_address has 0-4
I want to display all the rows from the patron table and all the phone numbers of phone_type = '4'.

However, when I use the query below, I only get rows that have a phone{type of 4, not all the patron rows.

I tried to get Access 2007 query designer to do this, but something is off-kilter. Patron_address rows have an address_type.  Only patron_address rows with address_type 1 have a child phone record.

So how do I get all the patron rows regardless of whether they have a patron_phone of phone_type 1?

```
SELECT 
    PATRON.patron_id, PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE,
    PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER, PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE
FROM 
    (PATRON 
INNER JOIN 
    PATRON_ADDRESS ON PATRON.PATRON_ID = PATRON_ADDRESS.PATRON_ID) 
LEFT JOIN 
    PATRON_PHONE ON PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = PATRON_PHONE.ADDRESS_ID
WHERE 
    (((PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE) = '4'))
ORDER BY 
    PATRON.patron_id;
```

If I add the criterion that the address type must equal 1, I get absolutely nothing back, even though this combination exists in the database. Isn't the behavior I want the point of a left outer join? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an **INNER JOIN** from the **Patron** table to **Patron_Addr**. This means that there must be matching records in both tables (by PATRON_ID) to return a value.

```
SELECT PATRON.patron_id, PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE, PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER, PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE 
FROM PATRON 
INNER JOIN PATRON_ADDRESS ON PATRON.PATRON_ID = PATRON_ADDRESS.PATRON_ID
LEFT JOIN PATRON_PHONE ON PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = PATRON_PHONE.ADDRESS_ID 
WHERE PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE = 4 
ORDER BY PATRON.patron_id
```

You have a **LEFT JOIN** from address to table so there doesn't need to be a matching phone number.

Since you are filtering for a Phone Type of 4, it will ONLY allow records that do have a phone record where the PHONE_TYPE = 4.

Is your Phone Type field a number or text? SQL Server will try to convert them back and forth but others may not and give an error or just not match - I don't remember how Access might handle this situation.

If you remove the PHONE TYPE criteria, your address criteria should work.

If you want to get all records of parton with address 1 but only phone numbers that are TYPE = 4, change the WHERE PHONE_TYPE=4 to part of the LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT PATRON.patron_id, PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE, PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER, PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE 
FROM PATRON 
INNER JOIN PATRON_ADDRESS ON PATRON.PATRON_ID = PATRON_ADDRESS.PATRON_ID
LEFT JOIN PATRON_PHONE ON PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = PATRON_PHONE.ADDRESS_ID AND PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE = 4 
WHERE PATRON_PHONE.ADDRESS_TYPE = 1 
ORDER BY PATRON.patron_id
```

**Access SQL:**

```
SELECT PATRON.patron_id, P_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE, P_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER, PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE 
FROM PATRON 
INNER JOIN PATRON_ADDRESS ON PATRON.PATRON_ID = PATRON_ADDRESS.PATRON_ID
LEFT JOIN [SELECT * FROM PATRON_PHONE WHERE PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE = 4 ]. AS P_PHONE ON PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = P_PHONE.ADDRESS_ID 
WHERE PATRON_PHONE.ADDRESS_TYPE = 1 
ORDER BY PATRON.patron_id
```

Access has some goofy syntax for subqueries. You could create a separate query for the P_Phone subquery instead but the results would (should?) be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, patron_phone rows only exist for patron_address rows of address_type 1. So the revised join will get me every patron_phone row regardless of the phone number type. I have not had a problem with Access pulling phone numbers. The data was stored as text.

Comment: The **ON** condition of `AND PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE = 4` would limit the results of the phone numbers to type **4**.

Comment: Thanks. However, Access says of this part, LEFT JOIN PATRON_PHONE ON PATRON_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = PATRON_PHONE.ADDRESS_ID AND PATRON_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE = "4" , "Join syntax not supported". I have never seen a join with multiple ON clauses.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used access queries - I had been mostly making pass-thru queries last I used it. It seems you need non-standard syntax for this. I updated my answer.